# How to acces a model attribute from another model

Tags: django, django-models, model

I newbie with Django Framework and I wish to know if is possible I access a attribute from the model X via model Y...In my case a have a model called "Evaluation" this model receive the scores of evaluations of the candidates..they have a ForeignKey that receive the Candidate(what is another model) and a PositiveIntegerField with receive a score what I want is access this PositiveIntegerField via Candidate model, it's possible?

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField
from site_.settings import MEDIA_ROOT
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class Criterion(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Candidate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    e_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default = '')
    github = models.URLField(default = '')
    linkedin = models.URLField(max_length=100, default = '')
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default = '')
    higher_education = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/douglas/Documentos/Django/my-second-blog/site_/media', null=True, blank=True)

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Evaluation(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
    criterion = models.ForeignKey(Criterion, default='')
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0, validators=[MaxValueValidator(10)])
    appraiser = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.candidate)

#model de teste
class Teste(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def  __str__(self):
        return str(self.nome)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a two solution to access the Evaluation objects

**Example 1**

```
candidateObj = Candidate.objects.get(id=your_candidate_id)
evaluationObjs = Evaluation.objects.filter(candidate=candidateObj)
```

**Example 2**

```
evaluationObjs = candidateObj.evaluation_set.all()
```

If you create only one Evaluation object then you directly use

```
score = candidateObj.evaluation_set.get().score
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the attention, but when I try to type this to test in the shell (manage.py shell) In the first I receive the follow error:"ValueError: Cannot query "Candidato4": Must be "Candidate" instance."
I put a Candidate obj inside the variable 'cand'...When I type the second tip I receive:"AttributeError: 'Evaluation' object has no attribute 'evaluation_set'"
The same error for the third tip...

Comment: I understanding but I cant make a attribute that receive a querry set, right?I try 'cand =  Candidate.objects.get(name=self.candidate)' and receive: AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'model'

Comment: You can try `Candidate.objects.get(name=self.name)`

Comment: Don't work: "NameError: name 'self' is not defined" =[

Comment: What is self parameter? Is it Candidate instance? If yes then above query run if not then try this one `Candidate.objects.get(name="Your Candidate Name")`

Comment: Would not the 'self' be to take a value of 'itself'? In case I want the candidate that the current Evaluation object receives ... and you recommended it myself ...

Answer (score 1):

Like other answers, you use [backwards relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) in Django.

See example: [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

And [Examples of model relationship API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Candidate_obj.evaluation_set.all()[0].score
```

Since you are using a `Foriegn Key`, there is chance to multiple `Evaluation` objects.So `Candidate_obj.evaluation_set.all()` may get more than one objects.

Comment: the 'Candidate_obj' and 'evaluation_set' be the Querryset of the models? (Model.objects.all()) ?

Comment: Candidate_obj is one object of model `Candidate`. Will get like `Candidate.objects.get(id=myid)`